# How to mark as read all messages in an Outlook folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Whenever I mark messages as read, depending on folder, some messages are still left as unread. It could be that some messages are on the server (I have no idea how to see the messages in the server only)

1. How do I mark all messages as read, even those that are only in the server?
2. How do I see the messages in the server?

Comment: `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+Q`, this should do the work

Comment: What happens when you right click the folder and select Mark All as Read?

Comment: @ShiffleMcDoobles as said, for one particular folder some messages (in this case 1), remain unread, no matter how often I do that. I think there is an unread message in the server.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it works. What command is that running? How can I reach that command from the menus?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, Crtl+A select all the messages, not sure where in menu is this available (with this ribbon interface). Ctrl+Q you can find as right click, Mark As Read. But I see there is also:  Folder->Mark All as Read

Comment: @RomeoNinov "Mark all as read" does not mark the messages in the server as read, just the ones in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Exchange Server, you need to open the mailbox in Online Mode to be able to see server-only messages. You can create a separate Outlook profile for that and disable Cached Mode for it. After that you'll be able to login to this profile and mark all messages as read.